# Mostrar filas aunque las clausulas del where esten vacias

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-12c

Poseo la tabla Automovil como se puede mostrar en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo mostrar matricula, marca, precio, nombre, asientos y color, pero en la clausula

> WHERE

`WHERE matricula = '123abc' or marca = 'Toyota'`

es necesario que no sea **OR**, por ejemplo tiene en la clausula where 3 parametros de busqueda, pueden ser nombre, precio, matricula o cualquier otro, los parametros pueden o no llevar informacion, pero si no encuentra por ninguno de los parametros debe obtener todas las tuplas de la tabla, ahora si encuentra por al menos un parametro, solo debe de mostrar por ese parametro encontrado, puede encontrar por 2 o **N** parametros que se le agreguen a la clausula.

he estado realizando mis pruebas por ejemplo con el siguiente codigo

```
SELECT  
   matricula, marca, precio, nombre, asientos, color
FROM 
   Automovil
WHERE
   matricula = '123'
   OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Automovil)
```

pero lo que hace es devolverme todas las filas, aunque haya encontrado primero solo por matricula *123*

por ejemplo si pongo en el query anterior

```
WHERE matricula = '' ...
```

deberia de retornarme todos los registros, si agrego otra clausula como la siguiente

```
WHERE matricula = '' AND asientos = '4' ...
```

deberia de retornar 2 tuplas y si por ejemplo la clausula quedara de la siguiente forma

```
WHERE matricula = '' AND asientos = '' ...
```

Deberia de retornarme todas las filas, abra alguna forma de poder realizar el query de esta manera? muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Se me ocurre que intentes algo así como `(<el_parámetro> IS NULL OR <la_columna> = <el_parámetro>)` y así por cada columna (sin olvidar los paréntesis).

Comment: necesitas un query dinamico, que se arme segun las clausulas que vienen.. o usar un truco.. que no me gusta.. pero es valido...

Comment: asi es, es un query dinamico, podrias explicar un poco mejor @padaleiana me quedo un poco de duda, gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: y el query dinamico lo tenes que armar vos.. no se arma solo...

Comment: Lo que mencionaba en el comentario es similar a lo que @gbianchi explica en su respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Lo mejor que podes hacer, es validar esto desde tu front, y solo mandar la clausula where que haga que tu query funcione.

Si no queres eso, es todo un tema.

No, no podes mostrar algo si no hay nada.. la DB no lo sabe (ah.. y son filas, no son tuplas).

El comentario que te dieron (NO_DATA_FOUND) es valido, pero solo sirve para PL, no para querys.

Si queres que tu query saltee las clausulas where, podes hacer algo asi:

```
where 
    (campo in (valores) or coalesce(valores,null) is null) 
and ....
```

donde valores es el conjunto de tus valores... y si no hay valores, tiene que ser null!

Que pasa con esto? bueno.. no respeta un solo indice.. puede llegar a tardar mil años... por eso, no es nada recomendable....